# node stream being piped before writing is finished

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

my buffer stream is getting piped before its completed writing 'response.Body' into it which is throwing this error:
`Error: write after end at writeAfterEnd`

```
var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
bufferStream.end(response.Body);
        var stream = bufferStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dlFile));
            stream.on('finish', function () {
                console.log('finished writing stream');
                cb(null, response);
            });
```

I cant use the event 'end' because it is a PassThrough stream. How do I make sure the first process is completed?

Answer (score 1):

You should write your data after piping it to a writable stream. That is `bufferStream.pipe` line should be before the `bufferStream.end` line:

```
var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();    
// pipe first
var stream = bufferStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dlFile))
  .on('finish', function () {
    console.log('finished writing stream');
    cb(null, response);
  });
//now write data
bufferStream.end(response.Body);
```